# How to filter query on a view of a collection in mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using mongoose, and create a view on a collection.

```
  NewSchema.createCollection({
    viewOn: originalModel.collection.collectionName,
    pipeline: [
      {
        $project: keep.reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: 1 }), {}),
      },
    ],
  });
```

This creates a new schema and only shows the fields that are passed in as `keep`.

This creates a model with this kind of pipeline:

```
{
  '$project': {
    uuid: 1,
    name: 1,
    description: 1,
    image_url: 1,
    price: 1,
    avg_rating: 1
  }
}
```

But when we do queries on the new schema, like this:

```
const res = await NewSchema.find({name: {$regex: keywords, $options: 'i' }}).sort({ 'price': -1 })
```

But the results always contain everything in the collectin. When we do the query on the base collection, the filter works. Is it possible to filter a query with mongoose on a model that's a view of another schema?

Comment: I think what is happening here is that the client driver/app is evaluating that javascript (`keep.reduce(...)`) _before_ sending the request to the database. Views aren't going to store dynamic javascript like that. What does the stored view definition report (`db.getCollectionInfos()`)?

Comment: @user20042973, it may be unclear, but the code isn't trying to store the expression, but the expression is evaluated to create the projection I want

Comment: Can you update the question to show what the stored definition of the view is?

Comment: @user20042973 just updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)` somewhere before all your models and schemas are created. Answered by [Valeri Karpov](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/discussions/12658#discussioncomment-4098900) the creator of mongoose on GitHub discussions.